# Does np.empty_like have a bug with the parameter?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

When i am using the function `empty_like` of numpy, i got 1 error and couldn't   explain it myself.

Here is the code:

```
In [38]: aa=np.array([1,2])
In [39]: b=np.empty_like(aa)    #it is ok
In [40]: b=np.empty_like(a=aa)   #it is wrong
TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-9b39ff78d8bb> in <module>()
----> 1 b=np.empty_like(a=aa)   #it is wrong
TypeError: Required argument 'prototype' (pos 1) not found
```

I have looked at the documentation, which says

> `empty_like(a, dtype=None, order='K', subok=True)`
>
> Return a new array with the same shape and type as a given array.
>
> ...

What is the reason? The  function has a formal parameter named `a`, but i can't use it to call the function. Surely ,it is okay for the other *_like function  with the `a`.

```
In [42]: b=np.zeros_like(a=aa)   #it is ok

In [43]: b=np.ones_like(a=aa)   #it is ok
```

Does someone know the reason? Or it is a bug?

Comment: `np.ones_like` works for me - is that a typo on the last line?

Comment: it is ok for me, forgot to change the code  when i use the up. i have change the post.

Comment: Do you mind reporting it here https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues ?

Comment: The issue has been fixed in numpy master: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/10210

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a bug in the `__doc__` attribute, making the help show a wrong function signature:

```
>>>np.empty_like.__doc__
"empty_like(a, dtype=None, order='K', subok=True)\n\n
```

and so on. Following the error though,

```
np.empty_like(prototype=aa)
```

works. That `a` I think is wrong. Probably a typo someone had, or a new programmer not adhering to the convention.

Comment: Indeed... see https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/cddee1d4b688bdc16d337721b2bdcd4db66949fd/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c#L1931